# Passing portletSession value from Java to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, websphere

I want to pass a value from my Java class to Javascript. I have set the value in `portletSession`. I don't know how to get a value from `portletSession` into the Javascript.

Here is the code I have used to set the value in the portletSession.

```
 PortletSession portletSession = request.getPortletSession();
 portletSession.setAttribute("noExist", noExist);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your title says "pass value from Java to JSP". Your question says "pass value from Java to JavaScript". What exactly do you want? JSP is absolutely not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: I am sorry. I want to pass the value from Java to Javascript. Sorry for the mistake. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use portletSession, use Cookie instead. You can access cookies from javascript using `document.cookies`

But there is another way: just print the variable into script block and javascript can read it.

```
var variableFromJSP = <% print variable here %>;
```

hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply Trinh. Can you please explain what do you mean by print variable?

Comment: Mean just like you render html out, how can you do that?

Comment: Hi Trinh, I did it in this way, var exists = <c:out value="${noExist}" escapeXml="false" /> but doesnt help. M I doing it right?

Comment: if it a string, you must have var exist = "<c:out value="${noExist}" escapeXml="false" />"

Comment: After that you can view source to see what printed out

Comment: But this doesnt return anything. It gives the value of the var as blank. Any idea??